# .htaccess (Dynamic Directory)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need help writing this `htaccess` file.

I have a custom blog and I want pretty URL's like
http://www.domain.com/YYYY/MM/DD/blog-title

to call http://www.domain.com/archive/?date=YYYY-MM-DD&title=blog-title

Then I can use PHP and MySQL to display the article. However, I do have other php files in the / directory. I think I Need to exclude those as well, correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ archive/index.php?date=$1-$2-$3&title=$4
```

Comment: Do I need to exclude /archive/ ? I get a 500 error when accessing /archive/ directly

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled and archive/index.php exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/([^/]+)/?$ /archive/?date=$1-$2-$3&title=$4 [QSA]
```

Comment: Neither seems to work. I get either a 404 error when doing /YYYY/MM/DD/title or if I go to archive/index.php I get a 500 error.